# How to pass data from one widget to its sibling widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Column widget which contains a custom widget (ViewCard) and a RaisedButton.
There is some data inside ViewCard which the user can interact with and change. Now, I want the RaisedButton to submit those changes or details to the firestore. The problem I am facing right now is that I can't access the custom widget's data from outside of it.

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20,),

          ViewCard(args.combo,_changeprice),

          SizedBox(height: 20,),

          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
            height: 75,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
            ),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 0,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                Text("Cart price : $price"),
                SizedBox(width: 75,),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    color: Colors.yellow
                  ),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: (){},     
                    child: Text("Host this order"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],)
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

I need to somehow pass 3 variables from inside of CardView to the current class so that I can use them in RaisedButton.

edit : args.combo is of type Combo

```
class Combo {
  List<Items> items;
  Combo({this.items});
}
class Items {
  String item;
  String price;
}
```

Here is the code for CardView. This class created a card for args.combo

```
class ViewCard extends StatefulWidget {
  ViewCard(this.combo, this.changePrice);
  final Combo combo;
  final IntCallback changePrice;

  @override
  _ViewCardState createState() => _ViewCardState();
}

class _ViewCardState extends State<ViewCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: (50 * widget.combo.items.length + 125).toDouble(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40), color: Colors.yellow),
      child: Card(
          elevation: 0,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: widget.combo.items.length,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 25,
                    ),
                    OneItem(widget.combo, index, widget.changePrice),

                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

OneItem is another class which iterates through combo to find the number of items in it. Each Item is printed in a row along with a CheckBox. The user selects some checkboxes and it is this data I need to pass to the top-most class.

```
class OneItem extends StatefulWidget {
  OneItem(this.combo, this.index, this.changePrice);
  final Combo combo;
  final int index;
  final Function changePrice;
  double priceval;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => OneItemState();
}

class OneItemState extends State<OneItem> {
  List<bool> Vals = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    int count = widget.combo.items.length;


    Vals = List<bool>.generate(count, (_) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          child: Text(widget.combo.items[widget.index].item),
          alignment: Alignment(-1, 0),
        ),
        Align(
            child: Text(widget.combo.items[widget.index].price),
            alignment: Alignment(0.1, 0)),
        Align(
            child: Checkbox(
              value: Vals[widget.index],
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  Vals[widget.index] = value;
                  if(value == true){ widget.priceval = double.parse(widget.combo.items[widget.index].price); }
                  else{double val = double.parse(widget.combo.items[widget.index].price); 
                         widget.priceval = -1*val;}
                  widget.changePrice(widget.priceval);
                  print('${widget.priceval}');
                });
              },
            ),
            alignment: Alignment(0.6, 0)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a variable "checkbox" in the Items class...

```
class Items {
  String item;
  String price;
  bool checkbox;
}
```

... and modify the checkbox variable of each item in the onChanged callback of the checkboxes.

```
Checkbox(
  onChanged: (bool newValue) {
    // set checkbox variable of current item depending on state of UI widget
    ...
  },
)
```

Your MainWidget could stay intact cause you already supply the ViewCard with the Combo object.

```
class MyColumnWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController myTextController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
         SizedBox(height: 20,),
         ViewCard(args.combo,_changeprice),
         RaisedButton(
            onPressed: (){
               // here we have state of checkboxes inside Items objects
               saveToFirestore(args.combo); 
            },        
         ),
      ]
   )
  }
}
```

> This is pseudo code written out of my head. So it might not compile
>   directly but it should get you in the right direction.

**Another way** would be to use a StateManagement Library like Provider (https://pub.dev/packages/provider). This is possibly the better approach long term.

Comment: The user isn't typing anything. They are selecting CheckBox and based on that I need to use the button.

Comment: so the button is always there and you need to know the state of the checkbox on press of the button?

Comment: The variable args.combo holds data recieved form an http request. This data is displayed in ViewCard dynamically along with the CheckBox buttons(which are also created dynamically). Now the user will select some checkboxes and I need to send this information back to the parent class.

Comment: tell me the data structure of args.combo

Comment: or better provide more code in your question so that people know what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the sort of thing that [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) would be good for. Though it is not the only option, it is the recommended state management solution by the flutter team.

Essentially, the problem is that the data stored in the vals array is inside the OneItem widget, which is deeply nested in the widget tree, and you want to use that information in another part of the widget tree. The solution is to instantiate the data at the root of the branches that will use the data, in this case above the ViewCard, and then use the Provider widget to 'provide' that list of checkbox values to both the OneItem widget and the button that is submitting the data using Provider.of`<data-type-you-are-providing`>(context).